# How to get a `Ptr` to an element of an `NTuple`?

Tags: julia

Say I have a tuple of `Cchar` like

```
str = ('f', 'o', 'o', '\0', '\0')
```

and I want to convert it to a more traditional string. If `str` were a `Vector`, I could create `Ptr` and do all sorts of things with that. I've tried various ways of passing `str` to methods of `pointer`, `Ptr`, `Ref`, and `unsafe_string` without success since those normally work on arrays rather than tuples. Any suggestions?

Note: what I really have is a C struct that looks like

```
typedef struct foo {
    char str[FOO_STR_MAX_SZ];
    ...
} foo_t;
```

which Clang.jl wrapped as

```
struct foo_t
    str :: NTuple{FOO_STR_MAX_SZ, UInt8}
    ...
end
```

I also played around with `NTuple` of `Cchar` (ie, `Int8`) instead of `UInt8`, and I tried to use `SVector` instead of `NTuple` as well. But I still couldn't find a way to generate a `Ptr` from the `str` field. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3):

Since you asked the question, I think collecting it to an array `a = collect(x.str)` is not the answer you are expecting...

You could use `ccall(:jl_value_ptr, Ptr{Cvoid}, (Any,), a)` to get the pointer of `a` even if `a` is immutable. However, blindly using it will produce some confusing results:

```
julia> struct foo_t
         str::NTuple{2, UInt8}
       end

julia> a = foo_t((2, 3))
foo_t((0x02, 0x03))

julia> ccall(:jl_value_ptr, Ptr{Cvoid}, (Any,), a.str)
Ptr{Nothing} @0x00007f4302c4f670

julia> ccall(:jl_value_ptr, Ptr{Cvoid}, (Any,), a.str)
Ptr{Nothing} @0x00007f4302cc47e0
```

We got two different pointers from the same object! The reason is that since `NTuple` is immutable, the compiler will do many "optimizations" for it, for example, coping it every time you use it. This is why getting pointers from immutable objects is explicitly forbidden in the [source code](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/master/base/pointer.jl#L140):

```
function pointer_from_objref(@nospecialize(x))
    @_inline_meta
    typeof(x).mutable || error("pointer_from_objref cannot be used on immutable objects")
    ccall(:jl_value_ptr, Ptr{Cvoid}, (Any,), x)
end
```

However, there are several workarounds for it. First, since the expression `a.str` copies the tuple, you can avoid this expressoin and calculate the address of it directly using the address of `a` and `fieldoffset(typeof(a), 1)`. (1 means `str` is the first field of `foo_t`)

```
julia> p = Ptr{UInt8}(ccall(:jl_value_ptr, Ptr{UInt8}, (Any,), a)) + fieldoffset(typeof(a), 1)
Ptr{UInt8} @0x00007f4304901df0

julia> p2 = Ptr{UInt8}(ccall(:jl_value_ptr, Ptr{UInt8}, (Any,), a)) + fieldoffset(typeof(a), 1)
Ptr{UInt8} @0x00007f4304901df0

julia> p === p2
true

julia> unsafe_store!(p, 5)
Ptr{UInt8} @0x00007f4304901df0

julia> a
foo_t((0x05, 0x03))
```

It now works. However, there are still caveats: when you try to wrap the code in a function, it became wrong again:

```
julia> mut!(a) = unsafe_store!(Ptr{UInt8}(ccall(:jl_value_ptr, Ptr{UInt8}, (Any,), a)) + fieldoffset(typeof(a), 1), 8)
mut! (generic function with 1 method)

julia> mut!(a)
Ptr{UInt8} @0x00007f42ec560294

julia> a
foo_t((0x05, 0x03))
```

`a` is not changed because, well, `foo_t` itself is also immutable and will be copied to `mut!`, so the change made within the function will not be visible outside. To solve this, we need to wrap `a` in a mutable object to give it a stable address in the heap. `Base.RefValue` can be used for this purpose:

```
julia> b = Base.RefValue(a)
Base.RefValue{foo_t}(foo_t((0x05, 0x03)))

julia> mut!(b) = unsafe_store!(Ptr{UInt8}(ccall(:jl_value_ptr, Ptr{UInt8}, (Any,), b)) + fieldoffset(typeof(b), 1) + fieldoffset(typeof(a), 1), 8)
mut! (generic function with 1 method)

julia> mut!(b)
Ptr{UInt8} @0x00007f43057b3820

julia> b
Base.RefValue{foo_t}(foo_t((0x08, 0x03)))

julia> b[]
foo_t((0x08, 0x03))
```

Comment: This looks super informative and very promising. I'll give it a go later this week I hope.

Comment: Very informative, indeed! Based on your info I was able to write a fast `unsafe_collect_ntuples()`, see https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/pull/50960

Answer (score 2):

As explained by @张实唯, `str` is a constant array which is stack-allocated, so you need to use pointer arithmetics to access the field. There is a package called [Blobs.jl](https://github.com/RelationalAI-oss/Blobs.jl) for this kinda purpose. As for the mutability, you could also use [Setfield.jl](https://github.com/jw3126/Setfield.jl) for convenience.

BTW, Clang.jl do support generating mutable structs via `ctx.options["is_struct_mutable"] = true`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for sharing those packages. `Blobs.jl` looks super useful actually for some other stuff I'm doing in my current project. `Setfield.jl`.... looks every bit as evil as `const_cast` in C++ (maybe more so since it works recursively). Very un-Julian. :P